# gcloud functions deploy: Failed to initialize region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

So I have this GCP project that is linked to a Firebase project (so I could use Cloud Firestore instead of Datastore).

I wrote a Cloud Function (in Python) and when trying to deploy it via:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy hello1 --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --region=us-central1
```

It takes forever and then gives this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Failed to initialize region (action ID: c6a9e29e404f3d1e)

If I deploy the same function in any other project that doesn't have Firestore, it deploys just fine...
Is this a limitation? Or do I need to set anything else?

Comment: I also tried setting the region with
$ gcloud config set functions/region us-central1
And also running the command without the --region arg

Comment: Cloud Functions now requires a Billing account in the project. Could you please confirm that your Billing account still works?

Answer (score 0):

Please try/ensure below points are in place:

- Kindly ensure that your Billing account is working.
- Make sure CloudBuild API is present.
- Turn off/on the CloudFunctions API in your GCP console.
- Retry deployment.

Comment: Thanks - I did try all that with no avail... I ended up creating another GCP project, then going to Cloud Datastore and selecting "Native" mode. After doing that, I was able to deploy the function. It seems that linked GCP/Firebase projects have some kind of issue.

Comment: If that is the case, I recommend you to try and file an issue for this to be investigated internally. Just select Create new Cloud Functions issue for your case.

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/20001), we can see that there was an issue when deploying Cloud Functions in us-central1 but it has been fixed now.

Please try to deploy again.